# How to handle Option of List in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

Suppose I have a function `getCustomers` and `getOrdersByCustomer`.

```
def getCustomer():List[Customer] = ...
def getOrdersByCustomer(cust: Customer): List[Order] = ...
```

Now I can easily define a function `getOrdersOfAllCustomers`

```
def getOrdersOfAllCustomers(): List[Order] =
  for(cust <- getCustomer(); order <- getOrderByCustomer(cust)) yield order
```

So far, so good but what if `getCustomer` and `getOrdersByCustomer` return *Options* of the lists ?

```
def getCustomer():Option[List[Customer]] = ...
def getOrdersByCustomer(cust: Customer): Option[List[Order]] = ...
```

Now I would like to implement two different flavors of `getOrdersOfAllCustomers()`:

- Return None if *one* of the functions returns None;
- Return None if `getCustomer` returns None and do not care if `getOrdersByCustomer` returns None.

How would you suggest implement it?

Comment: Does it really makes sense to return None instead of empty List? Just curious, in case you're designing this api.

Comment: I would like to distinguish between an error and an empty list.

Comment: @Michael But an error being thrown has nothing to do with the empty List. For error propagation, maybe an Either type is more useful here. `Either[Exception, List[Customer]]` makes sense.

Comment: @flavian You are right but suppose for simplicity I do not care _what_ error occurs. I just want to know if the functions succeeds or fails. In case of success the function returns a list (possibly empty) and in case of error it returns _None_.

Comment: A `Try` seems more descriptive than an `Either` or an `Option`.

Comment: @Dylan I will be glad to discuss `Try` vs `Either` in another question :))

Comment: Can I confirm... If *any* `getOrdersByCustomer` fails, you want the entire operation to fail? As opposed to e.g. returning a separate list of successes and list of failures

Comment: @Kevin 1) yes 2) I want _only_ successes and ignore the failures.

Comment: Factoring `Option[List[A]]` to just `List[A]` and using `Nil` where you would have used `None` is not a good idea when the empty list could mean something as a "normal" response. `getOrdersByCustomer` returning `None` would mean it didn't give you the list of orders, for some unidentified reason, but returning `Some(Nil)` would imply it successfully looked up the customer's orders and determined that they haven't made any.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should consider three possibilities--a populated list, an empty list, or an error--and avoid a lot of inelegant testing to figure out which one happened.

So use `Try` with `List`:

```
def getOrdersOfAllCustomers(): Try[List[Order]] = {
  Try(funtionReturningListOfOrders())
}
```

If all goes well, you will come out with a `Success[List[Order]]`; if not, `Failure[List[Order]]`.

The beauty of this approach is no matter which happens--a populated list, an empty list, or an error--you can do all the stuff you want with lists. This is because `Try` is a monad just like `Option` is. Go ahead and `filter`, `forEach`, `map`, etc. to your heart's content without caring which of those three occurred.

The one thing is that awkward moment when you do have to figure out if success or failure happened. Then use a `match` expression:

```
getOrdersOfAllCustomers() match {
  case Success(orders) => println(s"Awww...yeah!")
  case Failure(ex) => println(s"Stupid Scala")
}
```

Even if you don't go with the `Try`, I implore you not to treat empty lists different from populated lists.

Comment: `Try` is not a monad.

Comment: That doesn't comport with anything I've ever read. Could you please provide some reference(s) so I can learn more?

Comment: It's a little nit-picky, but given `fn: Unit => Try[Unit] = sys.error("")`, `Success(()).flatMap(fn)` and `fn(())` differ.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
def getOrdersOfAllCustomers(): Option[List[Order]] =
  for{
    cust <- getCustomer().toList.flatten; 
    order <- getOrderByCustomer(cust).toList.flatten
  } yield order
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
def getOrdersOfAllCustomers(): Option[List[Order]] = {
  getCustomer() flatMap { customers =>
    //optOrders is a List[Option[List[Order]]]
    val optOrders = customers map { getOrderByCustomer }

    // Any result must be wrapped in an Option because we're flatMapping 
    // the return from the initial getCustomer call
    if(optOrders contains None) None
    else {
      // map the nested Option[List[Order]]] into List[List[Order]]
      // and flatten into a List[Order]
      // This then gives a List[List[Order]] which can be flattened again
      Some(optOrders.map(_.toList.flatten).flatten)
    }
  }
}
```

The hard part is handling the case where one of the nested invocations of `getOrderByCustomer` returns `None` and bubbling that result back to the outer scope (which is why using empty lists is *so* much easier)

Comment: Thanks you :) but would not it be easier to define a _special_ monad `OptionalList` with its own `flatMap` ? For a case when I need this logic more than once.

Comment: Better still is to use a raw list and `Nil` instead of wrapping everything in Options.  `Option` carries no semantic meaning, so if you care about errors then you should use `Try` or `Either` (or Scalaz's `Validation`) and specify exactly how you want to handle/aggregate errors.

Comment: Rather than defining `OptionalList`, look into the `OptionT`/`ListT` monad transformers in Scalaz.